# webview remote debugging console commands with android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, google-chrome-devtools

So i got the remote debug system using chrome devtools to work...

The issue is I can not enter in any javascript commands to the console.

such as: `alert('test');`

it is like the enter button only gives new lines...

please help is there a setting I am missing?

Device update:

This happens regardless of the Android Device i am using...

I am using Chrome Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: You should give us more information. What software and devices do you use? What version of android? Describe devtools launch process...

Comment: ok I will ... ty

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to interact with elements or any other staff normally as you would with web application, if your setup is correct. You can see this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) how to setup webview debugging.

Comment: perhaps only a bug on linux...idk but it's setup correct

Comment: Maybe you already did read this, butt just in case you didn't take a look at this article: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

I was able to debug following this guide even on linux, if not you can always switch to different linux distribution